# Detecting exe 32/64bit

Tags: hex, 32bit-64bit

How do I manually [without any extra scripts/programs] see if a Windows executable is 32/64 bit?

I have been looking around and found what should have been my answer.
At 60 bytes in, the numbers below is suppose to appear, as far as I understand.

I386 0x014c

IA64 0x0200

AMD64 0x8664

---

---

### **Edit**

After jumping to the PE offset, I still did not see the machine type. I did a Find & did not see any matches [unless its near the bottom for some reason].
64 86 06 00 is not in the list above, so I dont know what I am doing wrong.

```
    Notepad.exe (64bit)

4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00
B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E8 00 00 00
0E 1F BA 0E 00 B4 09 CD 21 B8 01 4C CD 21 54 68
69 73 20 70 72 6F 67 72 61 6D 20 63 61 6E 6E 6F
74 20 62 65 20 72 75 6E 20 69 6E 20 44 4F 53 20
6D 6F 64 65 2E 0D 0D 0A 24 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
83 C2 32 29 C7 A3 5C 7A C7 A3 5C 7A C7 A3 5C 7A
CE DB D8 7A C6 A3 5C 7A CE DB C9 7A C5 A3 5C 7A
CE DB CF 7A DA A3 5C 7A C7 A3 5D 7A 33 A3 5C 7A
CE DB DF 7A D3 A3 5C 7A CE DB D5 7A CC A3 5C 7A
CE DB C8 7A C6 A3 5C 7A CE DB CD 7A C6 A3 5C 7A
52 69 63 68 C7 A3 5C 7A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 45 00 00 64 86 06 00 <--
B3 C9 5B 4A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F0 00 22 00
0B 02 09 00 00 A8 00 00 00 58 02 00 00 00 00 00
70 35 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
00 10 00 00 00 02 00 00 06 00 01 00 06 00 01 00
06 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 03 00 00 06 00 00
49 E7 03 00 02 00 40 81 00 00 08 00 00 00 00 00
00 10 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00
00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 CF 00 00 2C 01 00 00
00 40 01 00 60 F1 01 00 00 30 01 00 B4 06 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 03 00 B8 00 00 00
10 B7 00 00 38 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 E0 02 00 00 38 01 00 00
00 C0 00 00 F0 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
2E 74 65 78 74 00 00 00 70 A7 00 00 00 10 00 00
00 A8 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Comment: What kind of executable for what platform?  The answer will be different for Windows `EXE`s, Linux `ELF` objects, OS X `Mach-O` objects, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What appears 60 bytes in isn't the machine type but the offset of the PE header. (In this case, 0x00000100: 256 bytes.) The PE header begins: 'P', 'E', 00, 00. What comes after that is the machine type.

Comment: hmm.. I see the 'P' 'E' 0 0 now, but I dont see the machine type after it. I updated the message with a new larger sample.

Answer (score 0):

OMG Figured it out. The code listing AMD64 0x86 64  matches "64 86". I never realized it was flipped.